# How to get an object from NestJS container

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

How can I get an injected object from the container in nestjs?

This is something in Spring (Java). We can get the objects from the container like this:

```
CustomerClass myClass = applicationContext.getBean("CustomerClass");
```

Do we have anything in NestJS like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that exists.

This is how you would retrieve a service called `TaskService` from the app.

```
const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
const tasksService = app.get(TasksService);
```

Of course you should always consider if you really need an instance of a service outside of the NestJs module system. If possible stay inside the application and inject the services.

Comment: Looks good. I want to access an object within the nest application from the context? `createApplicationContext` will create the new context, right?

Comment: in the `main.ts` file there should already be a call `NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule)`. You can take the context from there

Comment: Yes, I already took that code. Thanks.